# Linear mixed models with factors as interaction terms: what is being compared?

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, panel-data

I am struggling to specify my linear mixed models, as I am relatively new to interaction terms.

Subjects were given a drug after the first observation, and the aim is to identify time points for which this blood parameter ("Value") is different across the study. Since there are missing values and unequal groups, my aim is to use linear mixed models to look for differences at each time point.

My initial idea was to specify models with the following formula using lme4 (and lmerTest). I've included an adjustment for their baseline measurements, since I expect this to influence the value once the drug is in their systems.

```
summary(lmer(Value ~ Time*Group + Value_baseline + (1|Subject), dt))

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     34.42820    2.97065 456.00000  11.589  < 2e-16 ***
Time1           -1.00166    2.33505 456.00000  -0.429    0.668    
Time2           -0.43548    2.33505 456.00000  -0.186    0.852    
Time4            1.01085    2.33505 456.00000   0.433    0.665    
Time6           -0.79818    2.33505 456.00000  -0.342    0.733    
GroupB           2.36570    2.31682 456.00000   1.021    0.308    
Value_baseline   0.22072    0.05590 456.00000   3.949 9.10e-05 ***
Time1:GroupB    23.29911    3.27618 456.00000   7.112 4.46e-12 ***
Time2:GroupB    21.88266    3.26768 456.00000   6.697 6.29e-11 ***
Time4:GroupB    22.47478    3.26768 456.00000   6.878 2.01e-11 ***
Time6:GroupB     0.07703    3.28502 456.00000   0.023    0.981
```

Looking at the output, I am not so confident that I have compared the groups I meant to. For Time1:GroupB, does this mean that Group B is significantly higher than Group A *at the same time point* or for Group A's baseline?

My intention is to test:

(1) At time point 1, is group B different from group A at time point 1?

(2) At time point 2, is group B different from group A at time point 2?

(3) At time point 4, is group B different from group A at time point 4?

(4) At time point 6, is group B different from group A at time point 6?

This is a toy dataset meant to illustrate the problem with much higher effect and sample sizes than I am actually dealing with:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggpubr)
library(lmerTest)
dt <- data.table(Subject = rep(1:100, each = 5),
           Group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5, times = 50), 
           Time = rep(c(0,1,2,4,6), 100))

set.seed(42)

dt[Group == "A" | Time %in% c(0,6), Value := rnorm(dt[Group == "A" | Time %in% c(0,6), .N],
                                                   mean = 45, sd = 10)]
set.seed(42)
dt[is.na(Value), Value := rnorm(dt[is.na(Value), .N],
                                mean = 70, sd = 15)]
dt[c(1,7, 21:25, 40, 60:77), Value := NA_real_]
dt[, Value_baseline := Value[Time == 0], Subject]
dt[, `:=`(Group = factor(Group), Time = factor(Time))]
ggline(dt, x = "Time", y = "Value", color = "Group", add = "mean_se")
```

Image upload is not working, but there is a visual included in the code. Will edit once server issue is fixed.

Comment: What level of "Time" is being the intercept ? Everything here is compared to the intercept. I see that group A is the intercept but I do know which time.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the section of code where I specify the factors. I've updated the code snippet. Baseline/Time zero is the lowest level of the factor, so I guess it is baseline.

Comment: What is the stat of your model ? Is the interaction significant to start with ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I was trying to ask a general question about how the interaction terms could be interpreted. In reality, I have 16 models ("Values") that I will need to build to ask these same 4 questions - some will have significant differences, many will not.

Comment: I think you should interpret the interaction terms if the interaction is significant in your full model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For Time1:GroupB, does this mean that Group B is significantly higher than Group A at the same time point or for Group A's baseline?

The four interaction terms with `GroupB` and `Time` show changes in the outcome variable for `Group B` at `Time1`, `Time2`, `Time4` and `Time6`, compared to `Group A` at `Time0`.

As for the hypotheses mentioned:

> (1) At time point 1, is group B different from group A at time point 1?

Main effect of `Time1` (for `Group A`): -1.00166
Interaction effect (`Time1:GroupB`): 23.29911
Total effect for `Group B` at `Time1`: -1.00166 (`Time1`) + 23.29911 (`Time1:GroupB`) = 22.29745

> (2) At time point 2, is group B different from group A at time point 2?

Main effect of `Time2` (for `Group A`): -0.43548
Interaction effect (`Time2:GroupB`): 21.88266
Total effect for Group B at `Time2`: -0.43548 (`Time2`) + 21.88266 (`Time2:GroupB`) = 21.44718

> (3) At time point 4, is group B different from group A at time point 4?

Main effect of `Time4` (for `Group A`): 1.01085
Interaction effect (`Time4:GroupB`): 22.47478
Total effect for `Group B` at `Time4`: 1.01085 `(Time4)` + 22.47478 (`Time4:GroupB`) = 23.48563

> (4) At time point 6, is group B different from group A at time point 6?

Main effect of `Time6` (for `Group A`): -0.79818
Interaction effect (`Time6:GroupB`): 0.07703
Total effect for Group B at `Time6`: -0.79818 (`Time6`) + 0.07703 (`Time6:GroupB`) = -0.72115

Comment: I see, that's what I was concerned about. Is it possible to compare each group at the same time point? As in, to test the four hypotheses outlined in the question? Do I need an entirely different approach?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @HarD you can run additional contrasts on your model to get tests for these hypotheses, for example via `emmeans::emmeans(fit, pairwise ~ Group | Time)` (where `fit` is your model object).

Comment: @PBulls makes a good point.

Comment: Yes, thank you both for the help. What's your inclination regarding multiple hypothesis testing following emmeans analysis?

Comment: You need to ensure that adequate adjustment for multiple testing is done.